# Should I make read excel file as an object in my python program?

Tags: python, pandas, coding-style

My project is based on the data i read from excel file, could someone help me is it good idea to read the file in a class method? Or what would be better solution?

Comment: Hey Linsaa. Whether you read your file within a class method or an ordinary function is a question of style and quite independent of your specific task (reading and working with an excel file). Searching for "object oriented programming with python" brings up lots of stuff that is more detailed than any answer we could give you here.

Answer (score 1):

One of the way to read excel is as below. I prefer this because we can do further more data processing, manipulation and analysis easily using pandas library:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel('filename.xlsx')
```

There are many other ways as well.

Comment: OP is not asking *how* to read Excel though, right?